CWT with daubechies wavelets
How are you? I need to know why CWT doesn't support the use of Daubechies wavelets in Python packages, when some older versions of Matlab do. What theoretical justification is there behind the impossibility of applying them in the new codes? I need to use both cwt and db6 in my research paper.
I've tried to make some modifications without success. Thanks for help!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
